# Does npm have something similar to 'yarn licenses generate-disclaimer'

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I'm looking for a way to generate a licenses disclaimer and the following [yarn command](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/licenses/) has exactly the output I need:

```
yarn licenses generate-disclaimer
```

The feature was removed from yarn with v2, but can be imported with the following plugin: https://github.com/mhassan1/yarn-plugin-licenses.

However I cannot seem to find a way to do something similar with npm.
I'd like to avoid having to fallback to yarn just for this...